# Whitespace in media query

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have white space on the right side of my page and I have no idea what is causing it. Nothing is showing up in my console that is showing the page to go past the 100% width viewport. This is happening in a viewport under 640px. I have checked all of the margins and I don't see any margins that exceed to the right or even ones that involve the right side of the screen.

Does anyone see anything that is causing this?

Relevant code:

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px) {
.project-flex-wrap {
    display: block;
}
.project_arrow_box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.project_arrow_box:after, .project_arrow_box:before {
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
}
.project_arrow_box:after {
    border-width: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.project_arrow_box:before {
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
    border-top-color: #00a16d;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
#project-content-wrap {
    margin: 20% 5%;
}
#project-box-title1 {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #FFF;
}
#project-box-description {
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #303030;
  margin-top: 40px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
/*-----Input div on project page----*/
.white-green {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#white-green-section {
    left: 15%;
}   
.project-input-container {
    top: 100px;
    left: 2%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.project-input-container2 {
    top: 30px;
    left: 0%;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.input-borderless {
    width: 87%;
    border-top: 0px;
/*  text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;*/
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: .8em;
}
/*---Project Scope section---*/
#project-scope-container {
    top: 70px;
    left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#project-scope-title {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.project-option-boxes {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #45ba95;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
    width: 85%;
    font-size: .9em;
}
.box_focused {
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position: 5% 50%; 
}
.light-gray {
    display: none;
}
/*-------Project Slider Section -----*/
#project-slider-container {
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 50px 2.5% 20px 2.5%;

}
#project-slider-title {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    /*margin-left: 40px;*/
}
#project-slider-description {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #2a2a2a;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
#sliderBar {
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    background: #454343;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.intervalCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background: #CCC;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.intervalCircle:hover {

}
.rangedot {
    height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0px;
    top: -8px;
}
#sliderInterval {

  line-height: 30px;
}
#sliderIntervalBudget {
    padding: 0 2px;
    font-size: .7em;
}
#budgetAmount {
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
```

Comment: I didn't see any white space on right side.

Comment: It creates a horizontal slidebar when there shouldn't be on.

Comment: I didn't see any horizontal scrollbar also.

Comment: I'm not sure how you aren't seeing it. I see it in Chrome and on my phones browser.

Comment: Maybe you and Becky aren't optimum web designers after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got the issue you are facing. It looks in smaller screen.

Just decrease width of `#project-scope-container` div to `85%` will solve your issue. Which is currently `95%`. And decrease left of `.project-input-container` to `0`.

```
#project-scope-container {
    height: auto;
    left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 70px;
    width: 85%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and catching it, It was one of those things where you look and look and look and can never catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this style and look

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
#project-scope-container {
top: 70px;
left: 3%;
margin-bottom: 100px;
width: 88%;
height: auto;
position: relative;
}


.project-input-container {
top: 100px;
left: 2%;
position: relative;
margin-top: -30px;
}
}
```

Adjust your `width` in `#project-scope-container` and remove `left` from `.project-input-container`